# Toggle next element only works within divs

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I have an article written and would like the hyperlink footnotes to toggle their corresponding references inline. So, example:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reference').hide();
    $('.footnote').click(function() {
        $(this).next('.reference').toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

html:

```
<p>
    Blah blah blah blah<a href='#' class='footnote'>[5]</a><span class='reference'>Doe, John. <em>The Book of Blah</em>. 2013.</span>
</p>
```

Which works fine—but in certain cases where formatting is an issue, putting the reference span **outside** of the paragraph tags screws up the whole operation.

```
<p>
    Blah blah blah blah<a href='#' class='footnote'>[5]</a>
</p>
<span class='reference'>Doe, John. <em>The Book of Blah</em>. 2013.</span>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to be really flexible, you should put the footnote number inside the footnote tag and the reference tag:

```
<p>
    Blah blah blah blah<a href='#' data-footnote="5" class='footnote'>[5]</a>
</p>
<span class='reference' id='reference-5'>Doe, John. <em>The Book of Blah</em>. 2013.</span>
```

As for the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.reference').hide();
    $('.footnote').click(function() {
        $('#reference-' + this.getAttribute('data-footnote') ).toggle('slow');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/next/

> **Description:** Get the immediately following sibling of each element in
>   the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves
>   the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

This means your code: `$(this).next('.reference').toggle('slow');` will only select a `.reference` element immediately following `this`. In your example `.footnote`.

This isn't the case in your second example, since `.footnote` is the last element in its parent.
To make it work you'd have to do something like this:

`$(this).parent().next('.reference')`